# write latency in burst

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

What would the following output from nodetool histogram indicate the possible bottlenecks to be?
What could the write latency be attributed to ;and any suggestions to improve it?
Help is appreciated.

```
Percentile  SSTables     Write Latency      Read Latency    Partition Size        Cell Count

                              (micros)          (micros)           (bytes)                 

50%             0.00            219.34              0.00            379022                 1

75%             0.00            263.21              0.00            379022                 1

95%             0.00            315.85              0.00            379022                 1

98%             0.00            379.02              0.00            379022                 1

99%             0.00            545.79              0.00            379022                 1

Min             0.00            105.78              0.00            315853                 0

Max             0.00         386857.37              0.00            379022                 1
```

Comment: whats the problem? the 380ms max latency? It was probably just a gc that effected less than 1% of write requests (less than 99th percentile).

Comment: 250 micro average on a single node seems on the higher side - it takes 350 secs to insert 100K requests of 360K each which seems a lot

Comment: thats assuming your doing them in serial. in parallel you could probably do ~100k+ in a second on a decent system with a good data model. With defaults I think its 128 Native Transport Thread active at once, thats 400,000 a second with 300us requests if that latency scales (it wont go that high though before it starts to slow)

Comment: by parallel - did you mean additional cluster nodes, more flush threads or some other.At the moment,we intend to find the best throughput on a single node before we add.

Comment: as in a single client to a single server making more than 1 request at a time. Use executeAsync or threads